# Prove that the intersection of two intermediate subfields of a Galois extension corresponds to the product of its subgroups of its Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

Let $F/K$ be a Galois extension and let $E_1, E_2$ be intermediate subfields of $F/K$ with corresponding subgroups $H_1,H_2$ of $Aut(F/K)$.
Prove that the intersection of $E_1$ and $E_2$ corresponds to $<H_1H_2>$,and $E_1E_2$ corresponds to the intersection of $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Answer (score 7):

1. Let $H = \langle H_1H_2\rangle$, then for any $\sigma \in H_1H_2$, and $x\in E_1\cap E_2$, $\sigma(x) = x$. So
   $$
   E_1\cap E_1\subset K^H 
   $$
   Also, since $H_1 < H$, $K^H \subset K^{H_1} = E_1$. Similarly, $K^H \subset E_2$. Hence
   $$
   E_1\cap E_2 = K^H
   $$
2. Note that $E_1E_2$ is, be definition, the smallest field containing both $E_1$ and $E_2$. Hence, if $H = H_1\cap H_2$, then
   $$
   E_1E_2 \subset K^H \Rightarrow H \subset Aut(F/E_1E_2) \qquad (\ast)
   $$
   Also, if $\sigma \in Aut(F/E_1E_2)$, then
   $$
   \sigma\lvert_{E_1E_2} = id \Rightarrow \sigma\lvert_{E_1} = id \Rightarrow \sigma \in H_1
   $$
   and similarly $\sigma \in H_2$. Hence,
   $$
   Aut(F/E_1E_2) \subset H \qquad (\ast\ast)
   $$
   By $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$, we see that
   $$
   E_1E_2 = K^H
   $$

Comment: Thank you .. you helped alot

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan: Is it true that the Galois group of $E_1 \cap E_2$ is the subgroup $<H_1,H_2>$ ? It is clear that $<H_1,H_2> \subset \ Gal (F/(E_1 \cap E_2 ).$ I don't know if the converse is true !

Comment: It follows from the Galois correspondence and what is proved in (1) above.